# CentOS 7 - Dependencies required?

Tags: centos

I have servers configured with Xenserver on a very limited installation of CentOS 7. I rarely work with linux, but when trying to install ClamAV I noticed there were essentially no basic libraries or plugins installed on my servers.

Is there an "all-in-one" package to cover all basic dependencies? Almost every repository I try to install has dependency requirements and those dependency requirements have requirements and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your quest for a package to cover "all basic dependencies" does not exist in CentOS/RedHat.  What is available are package "groups" that contain groups of packages and all of their dependencies (`yum group list`, `yum group info $GROUP`, `yum group install $GROUP`).  Though as you have found, you do not need to use any of those groups to create a functioning system.

Normally when you first install CentOS, you are asked which package groups you want to install.  You can select as many as you want to have them included in your base install image.

If you like small base images, downloading dependencies should not be too much of an issue.  If you have internet issues or need to install on a lot of machines, you might want to host your own local package repository.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's closer to what I'm looking for. I have several servers with xencenter and was unware the host had installed such a basic CentOS build without anti-virus. Unfortunately, this has left the servers vulnerable and I have found a miner running in the background hence the need for ClamAV. openssl-devel & libltdl.so.7 are required for ClamAV, but there could be hundreds of individual repositories required between the two. YUM was already installed on the server, but I thought most of these were usually installed with yum. Yum update does not appear to add anything new.

Comment: `yum update` would only install packages that are already installed and need updating.  If you do not like downloading lots of packages, you should add the packages you want in a new base image.  Downloading lots of dependencies should not be an issue for standard packages, `openssl-devel` and `libtool-ltdl` can both be found in the standard CentOS repositories along with all of their dependencies.  Add the EPEL repository, `yum install epel-release`, and you can have yum solve all of your `clamav` dependencies in a single command, `yum install clamav`.  Only two repositories required.